# Flex detect element in container

Tags: flash, apache-flex

How can I detect if there is any element in a container?

Example code:

```
<s:VGroup id="myGroup"></s:VGroup>

if(myGroup.getElementAt(0)){
    //Got element inside
}else{
    //Nothing inside
}
```

When I tried to run the above code, I get this error

```
RangeError: Index 0 is out of range.
```

How can I detect if there is any element loaded into the VGroup?

Thank you.

Comment: While the answer is simple [I posted] I'm not sure if I understand the rationale for needing to do this.  Why would your 'parent' need to introspect a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [numChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#numChildren) property.

```
if(myGroup.numChildren > 0){
    //Got element inside
}else{
    //Nothing inside
}
```